# suitable formula/algorithm for detecting temperature fluctuations

Tags: algorithm, firebase, math, statistics, physics

I'm creating an app to monitor water quality. The temperature data is updated every 2 min to firebase real-time database. App has two requirements

1) It should alert the user when temperature exceed 33 degree or drop below 23 degree - This part is done

2) It should alert user when it has big temperature fluctuation after analysing data every 30min - This part i'm confused.

I don't know what algorithm to use to detect big temperature fluctuation over a period of time and alert the user. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a period of 30 minutes, your app would give you 15 values.

If you want to figure out a big change in this data, then there is one way to do so.
You can use implement the following method:

1. Calculate the **mean and the standard deviation** of the values.
2. **Subtract the data you have from the mean** and then take the **absolute value of the result**.
3. **Compare if the absolute value is greater than one standard deviation**, if it is greater then you have a big data.

See this example for better understanding:

Lets suppose you have these values for 10 minutes:

25,27,24,35,28

**First Step:**

Mean = 27 (apprx)

One standard deviation = 3.8

**Second Step: Absolute(Data - Mean)**

abs(25-27) = 2

abs(27-27) = 0

abs(24-27) = 3

abs(35-27) = 8

abs(28-27) = 1

**Third Step**

**Check if any of the subtraction is greater than standard deviation**

abs(35-27) gives 8 which is greater than 3.8

So, there is a big fluctuation. If all the subtracted results are less than standard deviation, then there is no fluctuation.

You can still improvise the result by selecting two or three standard deviation instead of one standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. I think that is exactly what I wanted. Is there is any mathematics name for the above method ? It would be helpful to include that in my project documentation.

Comment: One follow up question, If 30 min analysis is not a requirement isn't it more accurate to measure huge fluctuation based on previous data when new data arrive since using above method may not be accurate in following case-   22,30,28,26,29,27,25,24. According to your method the huge fluctuation from 22 to 30 will not be detected. Don't you think 30 min fluctuation analysis doesn't work  ?

Comment: This method is called adaptive detection method. I think 30 min analysis should work too. The difference calculated indicates how much the value deviates from the mean. You can set some threshold for your 30 min experiment that if the difference results deviates one std deviation/two std deviation, then that indicates a fluctuation. You can try calculating for the data set you provided and see if your difference values are greater than standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining what you mean by fluctuation.

You don't say what temperature scale you're using.  Fahrenheit, Celsius, Rankine, or Kelvin?

Your sampling rate is a new data value every two minutes.  Do you define fluctuation as the absolute value of the difference between the last point and current value?   That's defensible.

If the max allowable absolute value is some multiple of your 33-23 = 10 degrees you're in business.

Comment: It is in Celsius. Even though if all values lies between 23 to 33, big fluctuation like 23 to 30 in consecutive data is not healthy reading. So you have a good point in defining fluctuation as the absolute value of the difference between the last point and current value because in the following case- 22,30,28,26,29,27,25,24. Fluctuation from 22 to 30 is big but not detected after 30 min analysis since other data will balance that fluctuation when averaging.